# Is this a good way to Encrypt and decrypt strings data

Tags: javascript, encryption

I have made this simple example below, and trying to encrypt/decrypt string.

But I cannot help wonder if it is the right way to do it.

Have a look below and see that if it will develops problems with different character/string.

```js
const getKey = (key) => {
  let keyNum = 0;
  for (let char of key) {
    let cCode = char.charCodeAt(0) + key.length;
    keyNum += cCode;
  }
  return keyNum;
};

const Encrypt = (str, key) => {
  let text = '';
  
  let keyNum = getKey(key);
  for (let char of str) {
    let cCode = char.charCodeAt(0) + keyNum;
    // what happend if cCode dose not generate a valid string
    text += String.fromCharCode(cCode);
  }

  return text;
};

const Decrypt = (str, key) => {
  let text = '';
  let keyNum = getKey(key);
  for (let char of str) {
    let cCode = char.charCodeAt(0) - keyNum;
    text += String.fromCharCode(cCode);
  }
  return text;
};

const testText = "hahhaha this is a test - هههههه هذا اختبار";
const testKey = "test Key";
const eText = Encrypt(testText, testKey);
console.log("Encrypt:", eText)
console.log("Decrypt:", Decrypt(eText,testKey))
```

Please look at the comment above in `Encrypt()` and let me know if it can really happen

#### Why I am doing this.

I want to use a simple encryption that work with js(react-native) and C#. I cant find any. That is why I am trying to build a simple plugins. C# will encrypt a js files and upload it to someplace and js will download those js files decrypt them and using Function I will be able to use them

Comment: This is basically just a Caesar Cipher, where the increment is a checksum of the key. It's not a very secure method of encryption.

Comment: Why is it not secure, Its almost impossible to decrypt without a key right?

Comment: You can just cycle through different key values to get the messages in milliseconds.

Comment: You use statistical analysis to determine the key.

Comment: [security.se] would be a better place to ask about encryption methods.

Comment: Why are you bothering with this? Security researchers have been designing high-quality encryption techniques for decades, use what they've developed. Any decent encryption method uses complex mathematics such as prime numbers and factorization, not trivial checksums and addition.

Comment: I want to use a simple encryption that work with js(react-native) and C#. I cant find any. That is what I am trying to build a simple plugins. C# will encrypt a js files and upload it to someplace and js will download those js files decrypt them and using `Function` I will be able to use them

Comment: "*Is this a good way to encrypt and decrypt strings?*" - **No!** [Don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/8749)! "*I cant find any*" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API

Comment: @Bergi please read `Why I am doing this`

Comment: @Alen.Toma It's not entirely clear for what purpose you are building this. For fun? Then you probably don't need to care about good crypto. As a learning experience? Then you'll need to learn that encryption is not simple. For a production system even? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First this is bad.
If you want a simple test to check your encryption (basic test) just enter the same char as the text and see the repetition of your output, just by that i can discover your key.

If you wish to use good encryption then use libraries made by professionals.

If you really want to build encryption by your self then sit with books and learn the subject, it is a very interesting but also very hard subject to master, no shot cuts here.

Good book to start with - 'Cryptography in C and C++'

Comment: That is way to complicated for me and I really do not have the energy to study maths again. This need Maths to be able to study this.

Comment: Yes my friend its alot of maths and heavy logic, i really recomand you use professional libraries for your code. good luck!